# Rails: improve if statements in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, model, solid-principles

My question is following: how to improve rails model code such like this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :upcoming, -> { where('date >= ?', Time.now)
                        .includes(:groups, :creator)
                        .reorder(date: :asc) }
  scope :past, -> { where('date < ?', Time.now)
                    .includes(:groups, :creator) }

  scope :connected, -> (user) {  
    user_groups_ids = user.groups_teacher.pluck(:id).uniq
    joins(:groups).where('groups.id': user_groups_ids).uniq
  }
  scope :created, -> (user) {
    where(user_id: user.id)
  }

  scope :filtered, -> (args) {
    filter = args[:filter]
    kind = args[:kind]
    if(filter == 'upcoming' && kind == 'connected')
      upcoming.connected(args[:user])
    elsif(filter == 'upcoming' && kind == 'created')
      upcoming.created(args[:user])
    elsif(filter == 'past' && kind == 'connected')
      past.connected(args[:user])
    elsif(filter == 'past' && kind == 'created')
      past.created(args[:user])
    elsif(filter == 'upcoming')
      upcoming
    elsif(filter == 'past')
      past
    else
      all      
    end
  }

  belongs_to :creator, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
  has_many :groups, through: :group_events
  has_many :group_events
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :groups
  self.per_page = 5
end
```

I am specifically talking about 'filtered' scope. In my events controller index acion I am always calling filtered scope providing 'filter' and 'kind' from params to get proper events, but I can't find a way not using those ugly if statements. My main goal is to make it SOLID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to move these things to a separate class, call it something like EventQuery and initialize it with filter, kind and user.

Then return an ActiveRelation object based on the Event model that you can then use in the controller.  All the code in your model related to filtering would be moved in there.

Your controller code would look like

```
@event_query = EventQuery.new(filter, kind, current_user)
```

and in the view, you'd access a method in the Event Query class

```
@event_query.results
```

Another note and possible solution, you don't need to make 'scopes'.  A class method that returns an active relation is just as good.

```
def self.filtered(args)
  filter = args[:filter]
  kind = args[:kind]
  if(filter == 'upcoming' && kind == 'connected')
    upcoming.connected(args[:user])
  elsif(filter == 'upcoming' && kind == 'created')
    upcoming.created(args[:user])
  elsif(filter == 'past' && kind == 'connected')
    past.connected(args[:user])
  elsif(filter == 'past' && kind == 'created')
    past.created(args[:user])
  elsif(filter == 'upcoming')
    upcoming
  elsif(filter == 'past')
    past
  else
    all      
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use switch case to make it more readable and move the scope block into a class method.

```
def self.filtered(args)
  filter = args[:filter]
  kind = args[:kind]
  case [filter, kind]
  when ['upcoming', 'connected'] then upcoming.connected(args[:user])
  when ['upcoming', 'created'] then upcoming.created(args[:user])
  when ['past', 'connected'] then past.connected(args[:user])
  when ['past', 'created'] then past.created(args[:user])
  when ['upcoming', nil] then upcoming
  when ['past', nil] then past
  else
    all
  end
end
```

then call it as `Event.filtered(args)`

Comment: Right. Straight from the official **ActiveRecord Query Interface** guide: ["Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes."](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments).

Comment: @muistooshort is there a reason why the class method is preferred over a scope accepting arguments?

Comment: @MrYoshiji Probably because it is less messy and it is "just duplicating the functionality that would be provided to you by a class method". You used to be able to say `scope :s, where(...)` (i.e. no lambda) so `scope` was a convenient shorthand; slightly less convenient now that lambdas are required and a scope that is more than a single `where` call quickly becomes an unreadable mess. I'm sure there's more history behind `scope` as they've dragged it kicking and screaming into the future but I don't know it off the top of my head.